# FileInputStream converting some values to question mark

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I'm still a rank amateur at Java, learning as I go, so please be gentle!

The forums say that I should use FileInputStream for reading binary data from a file. However, my subsequent parser couldn't validate the data correctly, so I generated a test file consisting of the sequential characters 0 to 255 from an external program, and verified the values using a hex reader ... so I'm sure it contains what I want. I got my Java program to read the file into a byte array using FileInputStream, then print the values one at a time using println. Certain values - specifically -127, -115, -113, -112 and -99 - are converted  to 63, (which equates to a question mark). Try as I might I can't get the values I expect. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? The files I'm dealing with are typically tens of megabytes, so I need to read the file in one go - a byte-by-byte apprach is too slow. TIA.

**My code:**

```
private static String readFileInputStream(String filename) {
  String sContent = null;
  File file = new File(filename);
  byte[] fileData = new byte[(int)file.length()];

  try {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));      
    dis.readFully(fileData);
    dis.close(); sContent = new String(fileData);
  } catch(IOException e) { }

  return sContent;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code part for this?

Comment: @Graham Post the code in the question and format it. It's not readable like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment above:

```
byte[] fileData = new byte[(int)file.length()]
// some stuff
sContent = new String(fileData);
```

You are creating a string using default encoding from bytes. It converts 8-bit `byte`s to 16-bit `char`s according to the encoding, and since some of the bytes are not considered valid in your encoding, they get converted to an unknown character symbol, which is `'?'`.

See:

```
private void p(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println((int)s.charAt(i));
}
byte[] b= new byte[]{(byte)219};
p(new String(b, "Windows-1250"));
p(new String(b, "Windows-1251"));
p(new String(b, "Windows-1252"));
p(new String(b, "Windows-1253"));
p(new String(b, "UTF-8"));
```

prints:

```
Ű
368
Ы
1067
Û
219
Ϋ
939
�
65533
```

I'm assuming you're working on Windows with Windows 1252 codepage. This codepage does not have any characters at position 129 (= -127) and so on.

Do not convert binary non-text data to strings.

Comment: Yeah ... I guess that would be the error. So I need to return an array of type byte, and manipulate them directly into integers?

Comment: Yes. You can consider using classes `com.google.common.io` package from Guava library for easier data manipulation.

Comment: Thank you - I'll give it a try tomorrow. It's just occurred to me (standing in the shower) that having joined the bytes into a string in the procedure, I then convert it back into bytes in the body of the program. How embarrassing ...

Comment: Thanks to you both. It's been a learning experience for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you finally posted your code. You are reading the bytes correctly, but then put them in a String. You are having trouble with character encodings conventions. A negative byte has the most significant bit on 1. A lot of encodings (like UTF-8) use this bit to indicate that a character is spread over multiple bytes. So, the application that reads the output of your code, will interpret this as UTF-8, possibly.

So, by using the [`String(byte[] data)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%29) constructor, you are interpreting the string with the default system encoding. This encoding will have trouble, because the input bytes are random as you generated them randomly.

Comment: Appreciate that Martijn, but my files are binary (actually WAVs).

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. Updated my answer.

Comment: OK. I tried reading by readLine at one point, and only got part of the data. Are you suggesting that the best way of doing this is to read indeterminate-length chunks between line terminators, then join them together?

Comment: Check the update. Now, you posted your code, we are able to help.